# List is copying the same row

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve a list of customers from SQL Server, problem is, the list is only returning copies of the same row. I thought about possibly adding a foreach loop in my datareader, but I'm not sure just how to implement that. Any help is appreciated.

```
public IList<Customer> GetCustomers()
    {
        IList<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

        var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        try
        {
            var command = new SqlCommand
            {
                CommandText = "SELECT * FROM customer",
                Connection = conn
            };
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            var customer = new Customer();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                customer.CustId = (int) reader["cust_id"];
                customer.CustCode = (string) reader["cust_code"];
                customer.CustName = (string) reader["cust_name"];
                customer.CustDescr = (string) reader["cust_descr"];
                customer.CreatedDt = (DateTime) reader["created_dt"];
                customers.Add(customer);
            }
            return customers;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to move `var customer = new Customer();` into the `while` loop (otherwise, you're only creating one instance of `Customer`, repeatedly overwriting its properties, and adding that same instance multiple times to the list):

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    var customer = new Customer();
    // As before...
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are seeing copies is because you keep adding a reference to the same `Customer` instance to the collection. As you update the object in your `while` loop, each reference in the `List` also gets updated.

You should, instead, be creating a new instance in each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
        while (reader.Read())
        {
          var customer = new Customer();
            customer.CustId = (int) reader["cust_id"];
            customer.CustCode = (string) reader["cust_code"];
            customer.CustName = (string) reader["cust_name"];
            customer.CustDescr = (string) reader["cust_descr"];
            customer.CreatedDt = (DateTime) reader["created_dt"];
            customers.Add(customer);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer it like below.

**Consider ...**

Why build a list when you might not always want to?

`SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand` and `SqlDataReader` implement `IDisposable`.

Why use a `try-finally` when `using` is simpler and equivalent?

Why not use object initializers?

Why return all columns when you only need 5?

Don't open the connection until you have to.

---

```
public IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString));
    {
        using (var command = new SqlCommand
                {
                    CommandText = 
                        "SELECT " +
                            "cust_id, " +
                            "cust_code, " +
                            "cust_name, " +
                            "cust_descr, " +
                            "created_dt " +
                            " FROM customer",
                    Connection = connection
                })
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return new Customer
                    {
                        CustId = reader.GetInt32(0),
                        CustCode = reader.GetString(1),
                        CustName = reader.GetString(2),
                        CustDescr = reader.GetString(3),
                        CreatedDt = reader.GetDateTime(4)
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then, if your need a list

```
var customers =  GetCustomers().ToList();
```